# Check if picklist value contains a string within a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, filter

I filter a list of records based on a check if fieldname value equals selected picklistvalue. My fieldname value can contain more values for example: value1;value2;value3. I want to check if picklistvalue is for example value2 that the record is selected(equal).

So for example:

```
 i=1;

checkCheckboxOnOff =[{"fieldName":"Categorie__c","picklistValue":"value2"}]

fieldName= value1;value2;value3

picklistvalue=value2



 serverlist= [ {"Id":"123",Categorie__c":"value1,value2,value3"},  {"Id":"124",Categorie__c":"value1"},  {"Id":"125",Categorie__c":"value3"}]
```

My filter is as follows:

```
var opleidingfilter = serverList.filter(function(item) { return item[checkCheckboxOnOff[i].fieldName] == checkCheckboxOnOff[i].picklistValue});
```

I tried:

```
var opleidingfilter = serverList.filter(function(item) { return str.includes(item[checkCheckboxOnOff[i].fieldName]) == checkCheckboxOnOff[i].picklistValue});



var opleidingfilter = serverList.filter(function(item) { return item[checkCheckboxOnOff[i].fieldName].indexOf(checkCheckboxOnOff[i].picklistValue) == -1 });
```

Comment: Whats `str`, `i` ... ??!?

Comment: @JonasW. a  string contains method see:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Comment: I do know. But your code needs a bit more context

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How about you provide the following: the value of `serverList`, `checkCheckboxOnOff`, and `i` at the moment you run this filter. In other words, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JonasW. updated my question

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan updated my question

Comment: Here's the thing. That's not verifiable, because it fails to pass basic syntax checking. Why don't you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945/215552 and see if that answers your question. Note that `indexOf` returns -1 if the string argument is *not* found in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the following working:

var opleidingfilter = serverList.filter(function(item) { return (item[checkCheckboxOnOff[i].fieldName]).includes(checkCheckboxOnOff[i].picklistValue)});